# error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException'

Tags: php, mongodb

who can help me i have this error when i want go to the file article.php:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'Invalid object ID' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/Site/Test/article1.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/Site/Test/article1.php(14): MongoId->__construct('
Notice...') #1 {main} thrown in

beginning of the file article1.php

```
<?php



      $id = $_GET['id'];
      try {
        $connection = new MongoClient();
        $database   = $connection->selectDB('test');
        $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
      } catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
        die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
      }
      $article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only catching an exception of the type "MongoConnectionException"  while the code is throwing a more generic "MongoException"

```
Catch(MongoException $e)
```

Comment: error is here $article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));

Comment: What is the error?     \MongoLog::setLevel(\MongoLog::ALL);